# split string in a column of a dataframe and return new column with split

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called dat which has two columns as below

```
col1   col2
chr2   atagaaaaatcggctgggtgcggtggctcactcctataatcccagcactttg
chr3   atagaaaaatcggctgggtgcggtggctcactcctataatcccagcactttg
```

I want to be able to split the string at a match for gtggctc and to return a new column with the match included up to a specified length (eg 10 further characters as follows

```
col1   col2                      new_split_col
chr2   atagaaaaatcggctgggtgcg    gtggctcactcctataa
chr3   atagaaaaatcggctgggtgcg    gtggctcactcctataa
```

I have tried

```
library(stringr)
dat$new_split_col <- str_split(dat$col2, "gtggctc", 2)
```

but it gives me two matches in one column and doesnt include the match itself. It also doesnt allow me to specify the length of the desired match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(stringr)
dat[c('col2', 'new_split_col')] <-  do.call(rbind,lapply(str_split(dat$col2,
     perl('(?=gtggctc)'), 2), function(x) c(x[1],substr(x[2],1,17))))
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
extract(dat, col2, into=c('col2', 'new_split_col'), '(.*)(gtggctc.{10}).*')
#  col1                   col2     new_split_col
#1 chr2 atagaaaaatcggctgggtgcg gtggctcactcctataa
#2 chr3 atagaaaaatcggctgggtgcg gtggctcactcctataa
```

Or

```
dat[c('col2', 'new_split_col')] <- read.table(text=gsub('(.*)(gtggctc.{10}).*',
         '\\1 \\2', dat$col2))
```

Comment: Is there a way of making the match and the subsequent string being the same string? At the moment it is separating the match and the subsequent string into two

Comment: Apologies I wrote before you'd finished. Perfect. I used stringr in the end. Thanks

Comment: clever use of read.table that wouldn't have been my first thought and looks really useful for splitting one column into many `dd <- data.frame(x = I(sprintf('%s_ %s %s_%s', 1:10, 11:20, 21:30, 31:40))); read.table(text=gsub('(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)', '\\1 \\2', dd$x))`